# Как написать свой тест?

Tags: c++

[image: Картинка с заданием.]

Штурмую с++. Но тут встретилось задание, которое я не могу понять. Чувство, что сам не разберусь... В принципе я даже задание не до конца понял. Класс написать я могу, но вот что потом, меня немного затрудняет. Читаю про то, как сделать свой Тест пока, ну и решил сюда выложить вопрос, вдруг не то требуется...

Comment: вы бы занялись чем-нибудь реальным, а то подозреваю, что эти задания делают, кто сам ничего руками не может

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо написать конвертер в Римские цифры(I,II,III...) из арабских цифр(1,2,3...). И наоборот.

Римляне использовали непозиционные системы счисления.
Перейдя по следующим линкам, вы можете узнать подробнее о Римских цифрах.

- [Как можно разобраться в римских цифрах | Русская Семёрка | Яндекс Дзен](https://zen.yandex.ru/media/russian7/kak-mojno-razobratsia-v-rimskih-cifrah-5bc4f438d1613800aa24c558/)
- [Римские цифры — Википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80%D1%8B)

Comment: Здравствуйте! Я уже написал. сложность этого задания уже средняя. А раньше я решал подобные, там сложность была легкая. Значит это задание хочет что то еще. Я пришел к выводу что автор задания хочет от меня написания теста для моего класса, проверить работоспособность может. К примеру вот часть кода, из похожего задания, но на си.  Test(from_roman, BasicTest) 
{
   cr_assert_eq(from_roman("XXI"), 21);
   cr_assert_eq(from_roman("I"), 1);
   cr_assert_eq(from_roman("XXX"), 30);
}